# Why does the ISS not use the most efficient solar panels available?

Tags: iss, solar-power

In [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9709/what-is-the-difference-in-solar-panel-efficiency-between-solar-impulse-iss), Geoffc's answer stated that the ISS solar arrays are about 14% efficient. Higher efficiency panels were available when these arrays were manufactured. Given the high cost per pound of launching stuff to orbit, why were more efficient panels not used? [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/total-mass-of-the-iss-solar-array) estimates the mass of the arrays at 30 tons. Double the efficiency (as seems to be possible with triple-junction panels), and you'd be able to halve that.

Comment: When putting something into orbit weight is a major concern, but so is reliability. It **has** to work, so tried and tested technologies are picked over new.

Comment: For a long time, the solar panels used in spacecraft had the reputation of being the most efficient available, due to their cost-is-no-object nature. I don't know how accurate this is though.

Comment: One less known fact about ISS solar cells is that they're double-sided (bifacial) to also charge by Earth's albedo illumination. Since this _reflected insulation's_ photon flux is much weaker, this would _reflect_ in ISS SAW (Solar Array Wing) total efficiency.

Comment: Even if the panels were not the most efficient in terms of energy collected per *area*, they might still be the most efficient by energy per *weight*.

Comment: Also, recall that the first array was launched in 2000.  Which means the design was probably frozen in the mid 90's.  So consider only available space rated arrays in the mid to late 1990's.  Todays arrays would of course be more efficient.

Comment: @geoffc That 1990 seems true enough, I found some research into cell separation and surface charging dating as far back as 1991. I didn't find when the first SAW was manufactured, and I assume somewhere between 1991 and 2000 and not before (such tests can be done on a boilerplate), but 14% efficiency (or 11.4% as I calculate for the first SAW delivered in 2000, with later ones delivered till 2009 possibly more efficient) was back in those days pretty much state of the art.

Comment: @TildalWave The way Space Agencies work, do you think that the 4 arrays are different or all 4 are identical, even as there was a 10 year span between launching 1st/last.

Comment: @geoffc Dunno, but I'd bet on them being upgraded with each new SAW delivered to the ISS. It wouldn't be the first time that solar panels would be upgraded during the design, last such example I know of was DSCOVR.

Comment: @TildalWave So I asked it as a separate question. I am betting they did NOT upgrade them.  But what do I know?  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As 2012rcampion noted you are using the wrong metric of cost in your efficiency figures.

Triple junction solar panels are extremely inefficient wrt weight when compared to single junction.

To understand why this is you need to understand what a triple junction PV is.

To do that I need to explain the major inefficiency of standard single junction PV is due to quantum effiency.

Each single junction PV has a semi conductor junction with an associated voltage or colour.

That PV junction will only give you energy for photons of that colour/voltage or bluer. So if you have a PV junction that is tuned to green, that panel would give no power under a red light.

Conversely higher energy photons (bluer) would only give off an electron with that same voltage (the rest of the energy lost as heat).

Triple junction solar panels literally stack a red, green and blue solar panel on top of each other to maximise both the number of photons turned into electricity and the electrical energy gained per photon.

But if you are stacking 3 panels you could just build 3 panels instead and place them side by side so they don't block each other.

So for a naive approach triple junction is 3 times heavier, but not 3 times as powerful.

Comment: this would be true if whole panel would consist of just p-n junction ... but there is considerable amount passive balast such as substrate ( silicon, glass ... ) contacts, and structural parts (e.g. metalic truss and girders )

if this passive balast is more than 33% of the weight of the whole panel (which I guess it is ... but I'm not sure) than going from 15% to 30% efficiency while would be usefull

Comment: The substrate scales with the number of junctions. The structural parts do not (by the way, glass counts as structural). However, you have to remember that solar panels in space do not need good structural support (zero g). I also completely neglected the non-quantum losses involved (silicon is actually not very transparent, extra layering decreases transmittivity). That is why I said that for a naive approach it is 3 times heavier.

Comment: but thickness of wavers is ~0.1-0.2 mm, while thickness on active junction is often just several microns. By "substrate" I mean that many thin-film solar cells (where juction is even < 1 micron ) are still deposited on some substrate like glass for structural rigidity (ISS panels are also rigid, so I guess they have quite thick substrate/support in comparison to junction thickness). ad "in space do not need good structural support (zero g)"  ... I agree I would prefer something like http://phys.org/news/2015-08-team-functional-ultrathin-solar-cells.html ... but this is not the case of ISS SAW