# How much did satellites and space exploration enable the development of solar panels?

Tags: solar-power, spinoff

After the demonstration of silicon solar panels in [1954](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200904/physicshistory.cfm), Bell Labs struggled to find [demand](http://californiasolarcenter.org/history-pv/) for the solar panels as they were too expensive for most mainstream applications. However, satellites needed a power source to recharge batteries and it was here solar power found an anchor customer. There is mention of $300 per watt in 1956 to 100 per watt in early 1970s when it was first applied to Earth markets in the previous link, however this doesn't cover the relevant improvements and what happened in this period.

Basically how much did solar panels improve and develop as a result of being used to power satellites?

Comment: The improvements may not be significant due to the physical limitations of photovoltaics. The main technology improvements are radiation resistance. The first solar panels under the influence of space conditions were destroyed for about a year.

Comment: @A.Rumlin That's a great point. Damage rates due to charged particles (e.g. protons) and also neutrons would be a big problem for semiconductors. A very important requirement for many satellites (but not all, e.g. ISS) is efficiency, so its possible that space applications pushed the development of double and triple-junction cells fairly hard.

Comment: See [Were solar concentrators on HS-702 just a stop-gap measure until triple-junction PV cells were available?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21410) (as yet unanswered) and [Has the choice of photovoltaic junction types for newer spacecraft converged on one, optimal solution?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17343)) and [Why did Deep Space 1 use solar concentrators?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34119) and [Why are these multi-junction solar cells 40% efficient on earth but 30% in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17784)

Comment: In Norway, the big consumer of early commercial solar panels was the coastal department. Thousands of kerosene fuelled navigation lights were switched to electrical power. The investment was costly, but saved money in the long run by not requiring an enormous amount of refuelling trips a year.

Comment: You 'improvements' seem focused on cost per Watt - is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I think the question is, did the market for solar panels to use in space lead to developments that made them cheap enough for other uses?